# Append matched value of list in scala

Tags: scala, list, for-loop, append, immutability

How do I append this list:

```
val aList = List(List(8),List(7),List(6),List(4),List(9))
```

based on:

```
val aUpdate = List(8,7,4,2,9)
```

and the output should be:

```
val aList = List(List(8,8), List(7,7),List(6),List(4),List(9,9))
```

I had expected the following code to work:

```
val aList = for (i <- 1 to 4) aList map (_(i)) {
case if aList map (_(i)) contains aUpdate(i) => ++ List(map.aUpdate(i))
```

Anyone could tell me what is the valid argument for the output? and please explain the detail how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not really valid. There are couple of things missing, such as pattern identifier after `case`, list value before concatenation, closing bracket etc.

Here's one way to do it:

```
val r = (aList zip aUpdate).map {
  case (list, update) if (list.contains(update)) => update :: list
  case (list, update) => list
}

// result: List(List(8, 8), List(7, 7), List(6), List(4), List(9, 9))
```

Zipping one list with another results in a list of pairs, where n-th pair consists of n-th element from the first list and n-th element from the second list. Now you can easily do what you want; if element that comes from `aList` contains the element that comes from `aUpdate` then add it to the list, otherwise (note that second case has same identifiers, but no condition) just return the element from `aList`.

Comment: Good answer! I've tried to left the second case blank to eliminate 6 and 4. But why it bring blank list to `r`? so the result become `r: List[Any] = List(List(8, 8), List(7, 7), (), (), List(9, 9))`

Comment: Because you return an empty value, or more technically, a `Unit` value. Try filtering first and then map: 
  `(aList zip aUpdate).filter {
      case (list, update) => (list.contains(update))
    }.map {
      case (list, update) => update :: list
    }`
Note that you can also use `withFilter` instead of `filter` to avoid creating the intermediate collection (that is, you will filter and map in one pass that way; withFilter simply restricts the domain for the upcoming map).